# White listing vulnerable parameters within Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, penetration-testing

I have an issue where potentials attackers can gain access to potentially sensitive information such as a web config file through one of my controller methods

```
public ActionResult GetPdfContent(string fileCode)
{
    try
    {
        var relativePath = "~/files/content/" + fileCode;
        if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(relativePath)))
        {

            return File("~/files/content/" + fileCode, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(fileCode));
        }
        else
        {
            return View("ErrorNotExistsView");
        }

    }
}
```

As a recommendation the files codes should be white-listed for one.

Could it be as simple as adding a collection such as a list with all the white listed content and returning  an error if the parameter is not contained within the list?

```
List<string> lstWhitelistedContent = new List<string>() { "code1", "code2", "code3"};
if (!lstWhitelistedContent.Contains(fileCode))
{
    return View("ErrorNotExistsView");
}
```

Comment: Using a whitelist is a good way to protect you against hackers guessing for content. There are examples where documents where 'leaked' too early because someone guessed that for instance http://example.com/docs/somedoc2014.pdf might be found at  http://example.com/docs/somedoc2015.pdf a year later.

Comment: Btw, your whitelist is now a blacklist: serves everything except code1 through code 3.

Comment: why don't you just put all the downloadable files in one directory and only allow download from that path? Any other path just bounce

Comment: Good idea, thanks, will do it that way...make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to white-list a directory rather than list of files, and apparently your `/files/content` directory already seem like a good candidate.

Also, judging by the name of your method, it should only serve `.pdf` files, so you can add another restriction by the file extension.

Try this instead:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetPdfContent(string fileCode)
{
    // this will remove path traversal attempts like '..'
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileCode);

    // this will get you the file extension
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLowerInvariant();

    if (fileExtension != ".pdf")
        return View("ErrorNotExistsView");

    return File("~/files/content/" + fileName, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(fileName));   
    }
}
```

Also, I took the liberty to remove the authorization check in the method and placed an `[Authorize]` attribute instead.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the input...for me still a learning process